# awk doesn't print separator

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm running this awk program :

```
awk -F: '{if($1=="waheed") {$2=1;print $0}}' /etc/passwd
```

and the output is:

```
mysql 1 118 129 MySQL Server,,, /nonexistent /bin/false
```

without the `:` separator, how to make it print the line in this case with the separator?
note : this happened after writing the expression `$2=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk output is seperated by the contents of the OFS ( output field seperater ) variable a space by default.  This can be set with -v OFS=':'

```
awk -F : -v OFS=':' '{ cmds}' file
```

Comment: thank you.. another question, I wan't to write the awk output to the file, I use this
`awk -F : -v OFS=':' '{ cmds}' file >> file` but this appends to the file.. tried ">"  to over-write but it doesn't work.. it make the file blank.

Comment: Yeah bash truncates the file before awk has a chance to read the contents. Cat on mat has a good explaination of redirections [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/)

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use awk command like this :

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} {your code here}'
```

all codes in begin quotes runs only onetime

and the -v option is for to trans your parameter into your scripts. like:

```
awk '{print $pid_doc}' -v pid_doc="$Param"
```

and this $Param can be given from your shell script